# How to select an entry in a combobox using jquery?

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors, drop-down-menu

I have a HTML combobox which has two entries. One is blank and the other is some text.  I don't know what the values are.

Is there anyway by using jquery (given the constaint above) that I can have the entry with text in it programtically selected in the combobox?

Comment: please show us the html and what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one way to do it

assuming this is the html

```
<select size="5" id="foobar">
   <option value="">foo</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```

here is the jquery

```
$('#foobar option:nth-child(2)').prop('selected',true);
```

here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/BPV2z/)

Comment: It's worth noting that `.prop('selected',true)` requires jQuery 1.6+, whereas `.attr('selected', 'selected')` works in all versions of jQuery.

Comment: @Tomalak  yes that is true I meant to point that out. I wanted to use prop with 1.6 to start showcasing the new method

Answer (score 1):

This selects the *first non-empty option*:

```
$("#mySelectBox").val(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i<this.options.length; i++) {
    if (this.options[i].text != "") return this.options[i].value;
  }
});
```

You could do `$.trim(this.options[i].text)` if the text can contain white-space.

It's a generalized solution, if you are sure that you always want to select the *second* option, a simpler method exists, of course - see [mcgrailm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227192/how-to-select-an-entry-in-a-combobox-using-jquery/6227298#6227298).

Answer (score 0):

How about sorting the list:

```
$("#combo").html($("#combo option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
}));
```

But out of interest, why doesn't the option have the selected value - is it created dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Pure JQuery selector that selects the first non-empty option (based on the text of the option):

```
$('#myDropDown option:not(:empty):first')
```

Using the following sample:

```
<select size="5" id="foobar">
    <option value="emptyoption"></option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```

This selects the "bar" option:

```
$('#foobar option:not(:empty):first').prop('selected',true);
```

Comment: this does not work see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/yA6AJ/) . Unless I'm missing something its still selects the empty item

Comment: This does work if the text of the option is empty. In your sample the value was empty and not the text! From the original question I took that the text of the option is blank...

Comment: ok given that scenario  it does indeed work to bad the OP seems to be mia would be nice to know the html really looks like